# How significant is the difference between difficulty levels?

Tags: dead-space-3

I usually play Dead Space on the hardest difficulty setting (except the "limited saves" mode), but it's been a while so I started up Dead Space 3 on the second hardest mode. While I die quickly, it's not all *that* hard.

So what all is the difference between the difficulty modes? How significant is each step up? Is it just that you pick up less ammo and necromorphs take/deal more damage (which I believe was how the first games work)? Does difficulty affect those all-too-precious resource drops?

Comment: I beat it for my first playthrough on 'Impossible' its bad but its not that bad. Being a dead space veteran you get the hang of it. Prepare to die a lot though...Also yeah less ammo but to be honest compared to old Dead Space titles its still too much ammo...

Comment: @Emerica. I have mixed feelings about the single ammo unit thing. I guess the new weapon system/plethora of guns makes ammo types unsustainable

Comment: @BenBrocka First time playing Dead Space and I feel that there are too many resource drops on every difficulty (save Survival/Hardcore which I haven't played yet). The only thing I noticed was that difficulty does not seem to scale for coop (or it doesn't *feel* like it), so coop Impossible is completely manageable whereas Hard and Impossible are challenging solo

Comment: Also, if you explore every nook and cranny you get an insane amount of resources by selling extras. I have no need for more than 2 frames of each type (since you can only have 2 guns) or most of the chips, so I sell them all the second I pick them up. You also get 2-4 of each engine so I sell extras there too. Between selling and diligent use of scavenger bots you can max your suit and guns early and still have resources flowing out of your pockets on Impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, each level (causal, normal, hard and impossible) increases the threat level of enemies and the availability of supplies. Higher difficulty means enemies will deal more damage and can endure more punishment before dying, and the amount of resources you find is lessened (e.g. a stack of ammo is only 3 on impossible, whereas it's 4 on hard and 6 on the easiest difficulty setting).

In addition, for New Game Plus
**Classic mode:**
In this mode you are restricted to building weapons available in dead space and dead space 2 from blue prints. Building weapons from parts is disabled. This mode also feature 'classic aiming' and a reduced number of inventory slots to begin with, increasing as the player acquires RIG suits. This mode has it difficult level set to hard. Finishing this mode unlocks the Devil Horns
**Pure Survival mode:**
In this mode enemies do not drop supplies. This mode has it difficult level set to hard. Resources must be used to craft all items at a bench. You also won't find any weapon part, circuit, frame throughout the game (which means you can't acquire the unique frames such as the S.C.A.F. frame, Weller's frame, Hammond's frame, etc.).
**Hardcore Mode:**
Dying once in hardcore mode will delete the save entirely and thus ending the game, forcing you to start over from the beginning. Unlike in Dead Space 2, saves are unlimited.